# How to replace default android loading image with .gif image in android application

Tags: android, loading

I have **worklight** android application and using default loading provided by **jquery**, want to replace default loading with another .gif image. can someone help me from where default image can be replace.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think, You have to place .gif image in a drawable folder and get that .gif images and place drawble folder,all the gif and image, application take that folder by default. If you don't have drawable folder create just under the res folder.

There is new library [Glibe](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for displaying gif file in android, It is easy to use, Like this,

```
String gifUrl = "http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--B7tUiM5l--/gf2r69yorbdesguga10i.gif";
ImageView imageViewGif= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewGif);
Glide 
    .with( context )
    .load( gifUrl )
    .into( imageViewGif );
```

Don't forget to import the **[Glibe](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)** dependencies on gradle file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my application is using worklight and calling native android in application is getting slow, so we dont want to use native calling. sorry but i forgot to mention worklight and jquery in question now updated.

Answer (score 0):

By loading image, if you are referring to splash screen, in a MobileFirst Hybrid application custom splash screen needs to be placed in "res/drawable" folder. However ,this cannot be a .gif file. It has to be a png.

For more details refer this [link](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_splash_screen_android.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is not related to splash screen, want to replace loading circle that is .gif image.

Comment: Are you referring to Busy indicator? please be clear about your query

Comment: yes, same we are using while page navigation, while server connectivity, while data loading for showing busy activity